# SQL: Expand 1 Column into 3 on Summarize Table

Tags: .net, sql, database, grouping, summary

I'm writing a program that displays products and the stores at which they can be located.

So far, I've been able to write an SQL query that displays data as follows:

```
Product    Availability
Milk       Store1
Candy      Store1
Eggs       Store1
Milk       Store2
Eggs       Store2
Candy      Store3
Eggs       Store3
```

Is there any SQL query I can use to have the products grouped on the Product column and the stores at which they can be located expanded into 3 columns as illustrated below?

```
Product  Store1  Store2  Store3
Milk     Yes     Yes     No
Candy    Yes     No      Yes
Eggs     Yes     Yes     Yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Availability='Store1' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Store1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Availability='Store2' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Store2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Availability='Store3' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Store3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: A good solution, but limited by the number of stores in this example. If new store comes up, the query will need update. @Martin: can't we make it dynamic?

Comment: @Kangkan - Depends on DBMS. Access has a `transform` operator. SQL Server would require the whole query string to be generated dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. Since the database is in Access, I used `IIf` instead of `CASE WHEN` and it worked.

Comment: @Alex - If you have the need to generate the columns dynamically when you add new stores then check out the [Transform Statement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/transform-statement-HP001032277.aspx) in Access.

Comment: @Kangkan - The number of stores are not going to change, EVER so this query is adequate. Just so I may know, Is there any other query which would do this dynamically [as in for any number of stores]?

Comment: if it is Access you can create a PIVOT query and get the results in the correct format

Answer (score 3):

A very common question. The word you need to know is **pivot**. Search StackOverflow for "pivot", or maybe "cross tab" to find a lot of discussions and examples.

Answer (score 3):

Most RDBMs support pivot nowadays.  It would help a lot if you specified which database you're using.  Some examples: [MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), [postgres (the crosstab function)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) and so on.

Comment: Copy and paste fail.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you don't know the column names before running the query, [this blog](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)
gives a good solution (but watch out for injection attacks).